# How does the compiler know that the comma in a function call is not a comma operator?

Tags: c, function, compiler-construction, comma-operator

Consider the function call (calling `int sum(int, int)`)

```
printf("%d", sum(a,b));
```

How does the compiler decide that the `,` used in the function call `sum(int, int)` is not a comma operator?

**NOTE**: I didn't want to actually use the comma operator in the function call. I just wanted to know how the compiler knows that it is not a comma operator.

Comment: you are talking about which one of the two commas...

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman; comma in the function call.

Comment: Why people are voting to close this!!!!!!!!

Comment: Disagree on this question being off-topic. The question asks a subtle detail about how a certain syntax can be interpreted by implementations and it can be conclusively answered by citing the relevant standardese quotes. *Efforts on trying to solve the problem* doesn't apply here. Understanding or hunting down standardese quotes is not really a trivial task.

Comment: There are two function calls, one to `sum` and one to `printf`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurs_check the compiler converts the C code to symbols and then performs an occurs check

Comment: I once had some C code behave strange because I was doing a division by an integer via a pointer. ie, the expression was `a/*b`. It was fixed by adding some whitespace: `a / *b`

Comment: @Stewart: I do not understand what do you want to say?

Comment: Just that a compiler, like any software, is simply a machine following rules. In my example, the rule that `/*` means 'start comment' is senior to `/` means 'division', `*` means dereference pointer. With your example it'll be something equally simple, such as `,` inside `()` means 'argument separator'. That's all.

Comment: «@SazzadurRahaman; comma in the function call»: but they're both function calls! `:P`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Look at the grammar for the C language. It's listed, in full, in Appendix A of the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf). The way it works is that you can step through each token in a C program and match them up with the next item in the grammar. At each step you have only a limited number of options, so the interpretation of any given character will depend on the *context in which it appears*. Inside each rule in the grammar, each line gives a valid alternative for the program to match.

Specifically, if you look for `parameter-list`, you will see that it contains an explicit comma. Therefore, whenever the compiler's C parser is in "parameter-list" mode, commas that it finds will be understood as **parameter separators**, not as **comma operators**. The same is true for brackets (that can also occur in expressions).

This works because the `parameter-list` rule is careful to use `assignment-expression` rules, rather than just the plain `expression` rule. An `expression` can contain commas, whereas an `assignment-expression` cannot. If this were not the case the grammar would be ambiguous, and the compiler would not know what to do when it encountered a comma inside a parameter list.

However, an opening bracket, for example, that is *not* part of a function definition/call, or an `if`, `while`, or `for` statement, will be interpreted as part of an expression (because there's no other option, but only if the start of an expression is a valid choice at that point), and then, inside the brackets, the `expression` syntax rules will apply, and that allows comma operators.

Comment: I had forgotten that there is a technical term with that name. I merely mean that any given token can only be understood in the context in which it appears. In other words, I'm using "context sensitive" as and adjective rather than a noun. However, I suspect that the only people confused by this were people who already knew the answer!

Comment: This is a good answer but you should also mention that the *things between the commas* are `assignment-expression` nonterminals rather than `expression` nonterminals (as discussed in Jens' answer), thus disallowing `,` at top level of a `parameter-list` from being the comma operator.  If the standard did what you describe without also doing this, the overall grammar would be ambiguous.

Comment: @Zack, quite so. I've expanded the answer with that info.

Comment: @EricLippert: I don't think it makes sense to say C has a context-free grammar. If you go that direction, then you could also claim C++ has a CFG (since, just like in C's case, it's ambiguous and requires a semantic pass to reject invalid programs). If you want to be really strict then you could also claim most programming languages do *not* have CFGs because they all require declarations before definitions before the program is deemed valid, which isn't context-free. Neither is a very useful definition since it puts most languages in the same category. (cont'd)

Comment: @EricLippert: (cont'd) ... from a practical standpoint (maybe not so much on the theory side) I feel a useful definition would be that C is context-free iff it has a CFG that unambiguously parses all valid C programs *assuming there are no undeclared identifiers*. But in that case, C is not context-free (and thus has no CFG) because of the classic `T * T;` ambiguity, which requires knowing what `T` *is* (and not merely whether it's declared). Hence I don't think it makes sense to say C is context-free.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I take your point, but you are using "grammar" in a broader sense than it is usually construed. The famous sentence "Colourless green ideas sleep furiously." is *grammatical* in English but it is *nonsensical*, and the sentence "Bob Smith is the king of England." is *grammatical* but *false*. The *grammar of the C language* does not intend to be one-stop-shopping for determining what is a *legal* C program any more than the grammar of English determines what is a true statement.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure I understand what you mean though. If a program is syntactically valid C, then the grammar must parse it correctly -- otherwise it's not the grammar of C. Ditto with the converse. If you define the grammar to be something that accepts syntactically invalid C programs as well, then how do you define context-free-ness? It's *always* possible to make an overly-broad CFG for a CSL (just accept every "tricky" string and leave the rest to semantic analysis...). What's your definition and what *would* it classify as context-sensitive, if not C? Why?

Answer (score 26):

From C99 6.5.17:

> As indicated by the syntax, the comma operator (as described in this subclause) cannot
>   appear in contexts where a comma is used to separate items in a list (such as arguments to functions or lists
>   of initializers). On the other hand, it can be used within a parenthesized expression or within the second
>   expression of a conditional operator in such contexts. In the function call
>
> ```
> f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)
> ```
>
> the function has three arguments, the second of which has the value 5.

Another similar example is the initializer list of arrays or structs:

```
int array[5] = {1, 2};
struct Foo bar = {1, 2};
```

If a comma operator were to be used as the function parameter, use it like this:

```
sum((a,b))
```

This won't compile, of course.

Comment: True but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Yu : I did't want to use comma operator. I just want to know how compiler know that it is not a comma operator!

Comment: @sasha.sochka See the OP's comment. He wants to know how parsers work, not how to use a comma in a function call.

Comment: @haccks Got it, edited my words. Using a comma operator as the function parameter is not practically useful, but knowing how to use it is still interesting, so I'll keep this part though.

Comment: @YuHao; Thanks dude! at least. And also thanks for edit to my post.

Answer (score 19):

The reason is the C Grammar. While everyone else seems to like to cite the example, the real deal is the phrase structure grammar for function calls in the Standard (C99). Yes, a function call consists of the `()` operator applied to a postfix expression (like for example an identifier):

```
 6.5.2 postfix-expression:
       ...
       postfix-expression ( argument-expression-list_opt )
```

together with

```
argument-expression-list:
       assignment-expression
       argument-expression-list , assignment-expression    <-- arglist comma

expression:
       assignment-expression
       expression , assignment-expression                  <-- comma operator
```

The comma operator can only occur in an *expression*, i.e. further down the in the grammar. So the compiler treats a comma in a function argument list as the one separating *assignment-expressions*, not as one separating *expressions*.

Comment: @haccks: a conditional-expression or a unary-expression followed by an assignment-operator followed by an assignment-expression.

Comment: I did't get your point please elaborate.It should be appreciated

Comment: To expand a bit on @Jens answer: let's change the problem and simplify it.  Instead of "expressions" let's have golf balls (painted yellow) and also big clear plastic balls that can be opened up and have stuff stuck inside them: `(` stuff `)`.  The grammar says, in effect, that you may have yellow golf balls, which are automatically separated.  Or, you may provide a clear ball *as long you've used both halves*.  The clear ball works as a unit, it can't be opened up and separated.  So: f( (a,b), g ) has one "clear ball" (a,b) and one "yellow ball" g and hence exactly two balls, er, arguments.

Comment: I ran out of comment room, so, continued, and back to the real C grammar: the parentheses allow you to escape out to a "full blown" expression, where commas are comma expression parts.  Until you have an "extra" open parenthesis, though, you're in this more limited "assignment-expression" sub-grammar (like the "yellow golf balls" idea), where commas are simply not allowed.  If the parser comes across a comma in this context, it has to stop and finish the assignment-expression.  This works because `(` "finishes off" with `)`: the bracketing ends the full expression context.

Comment: @torek; I did't get your line: ` *as long you've used both halves* `(sorry for my bad English).

Comment: @torek and also line:` *the parentheses allow you to escape out to a "full blown" expression, where commas are comma expression parts* `

Comment: Hm, I don't have any other natural language to express this.  Consider `{` … `}`, `[` … `]`, and `(` … `)`.  They "match up": if you write `a[3}` it's obviously wrong.  If you write `a[(3]` it's still obviously wrong.  `(` is ended only by the matching `)`.  That "closes off" the whole sequence, making it clear what goes with what.

Answer (score 11):

Existing answers say "because the C language spec says it's a list separator, and not an operator".

However, your question is asking "how does the compiler know...", and that's altogether different: It's really no different from how the compiler knows that the comma in `printf("Hello, world\n");` isn't a comma operator: The compiler 'knows' because of the context where the comma appears - basically, what's gone before.

The C 'language' can be described in [Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) (BNF) - essentially, a set of rules that the compiler's [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_analysis) uses to scan your input file. The BNF for C will distinguish between these different possible occurences of commas in the language.

There are lots of good resources on how compilers work, and [how to write one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler).

Comment: The question is about C. Talking about "parser" in the context of C++ is unnecessary complication.

Comment: @anatolyg - Fixed. I must have C++ on the brain at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

[The draft C99 standard says](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> As indicated by the syntax, the comma operator (as described in this subclause) cannot
>   appear in contexts where a comma is used to separate items in a list (such as arguments to functions or lists of initializers). On the other hand, it can be used within a parenthesized expression or within the second expression of a conditional operator in such contexts. In the function call `f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)` the function has three arguments, the second of which has the value 5.

In other words, "because".

Comment: my kids don't take that for an answer why should the OP... but that is the reason, because the ambiguous case is prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple facets to this question. One par is that the definition says so. Well, how does the compiler know what context this comma is in? That's the parser's job. For C in particular, the language can be parsed by an LR(1) parser (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser).

The way this works is that the parser generates a bunch of tables that make up the possible states of the parser. Only a certain set of symbols are valid in certain states, and the symbols may have different meaning in different states. The parser knows that it is parsing a function because of the preceding symbols. Thus, it knows the possible states do not include the comma operator.

I am being very general here, but you can read all about the details in the Wiki.