# compilation error in c statements

Tags: c, turbo-c

I am trying to run this code.this code runs successfully.But when i change variables to constant numbers i get compilation error.

My code that works fine:

```
 int a =5,b=6,c=7;
 int d;
 d = a,b,c;
 printf("%d",d);
```

as i run the code its output is 5.
but when i run this segment of code:

```
 d = 2,6,7;
 printf("%d",d);
```

i get compilation error.I tried i on other compiler also. But the error still exists. What i am doing wrong.

Comment: `int d; d = 2,6,7;` -- what do you think this piece of code *should* do?

Comment: i think i will assign 2 to d as c process this as queue

Comment: Read about the comma operator and avoid using Turbo C

Comment: check grammar : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17383834/1673391

Comment: What ***exactly*** is the compiler error your get?

Comment: but when i use a,b,c it runs

Comment: Works for me:  http://ideone.com/bVlqPi

Comment: My compiler allows `d = 2,6,7`.

Comment: @UnicoRahul: It would be helpful if you'd **post** the compiler's error message...

Comment: @UnicoRahul clearly, the comma operator does things which are completely unrelated to the things that you think it does.  "c process this as a queue" is completely nonsensical, I do not know where you got this impression from.  Just hit the books and learn exactly what comma does in C.

Comment: Also, you cannot be coming to StackOverflow and saying things like "i get compilation error".  You have to tell exactly what compilation error you get, and precisely on which line you get it.

Comment: Is the error "error: expected identifier
or '(' before numeric constant"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code use the variables and assignment `d = a` and b and c just as expression there, so run the code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 int a =5,b=5,c=7;
 int d;
 d = a,b,c+1;
 printf("%d",d);
 return 0;
}
```

You get `5`, `b` and `c+1` just valued and put them there useless.But if you run this code which includes comma expression:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 int a =5,b=5,c=7;
 int d;
 d = (a,b,c+1);
 printf("%d",d);
 return 0;
}
```

You get `8` as the last one valued expression.
You can use the number play as an expression with `()`:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 int a =5,b=5,c=7;
 int d;
 d = (0,3,1);
 printf("%d",d);
 return 0;
}
```

get the last number or valued data.

It works for me the code below:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 int a =5,b=5,c=7;
 int d;
 d = 0,3+1,1-1;
 printf("%d",d);
 return 0;
}
```

it output is `0`, but if you don't with `()`, it meaningless by this way, why not just use `d = 0;`